# Jenkins Codeception Phantomjs fails randomly

Tags: jenkins, webdriver, phantomjs, codeception, ghostdriver

I have some strange behaviour of my test setup. I have some acceptance tests written with codeception and run them on a jenkins server every 5 minutes. 95% of them pass without any problems but 5% fail with two different errors. Most of the time it is:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Error Message => 'URL 'http://www.waldhelden.de/' didn't load. Error: 'TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data.toString()')'
```

and sometimes:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

This setup is running on an Amazon EC2 server. At first it was a t2.small. After reading that these errors could be caused by weak servers I upgraded to a t2.medium (2 Cores / 4 GB) but the errors are still there.

Any ideas what to do to get this fixed?
Thanks, 
Udo

Comment: Did you get to know why it happens? Did you get a fix for this?

Comment: Not really. Its better now but still fails in maybe 1% of the tests. I limited to only 2 tasks running at the same time and increased the interval they run. Maybe performance is the issue but can not name it 100%!?

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I'm facing the "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died." I'll post here if I get more info.